# Search key inside array , how do access them in .where for searching

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to store my search keys in an array so that I can search in for multiple things with a single line of code but it doesn't work.

I'm using basic search exactly to this one https://github.com/rajayogan/flutterfirestore-instantsearch

what I have basically is multiple documents that have an array, an array consist of the map that has information like item_name, etc... what I want to search is the item_name.

I tried to put

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


//This class should take the array search which is  that I wish to be my searchkeys


class SearchService {
  searchByName(String searchField) {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('Foodtruckinfo')
        .where('arraysearch',
        isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
        .getDocuments();
   }
 }



 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
  import 'package:customer_register_login/Customer/searchmethod.dart';

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

     class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
   }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    var queryResultSet = [];
    var tempSearchStore = [];

    initiateSearch(value) {
     if (value.length == 0) {
       setState(() {
         queryResultSet = [];
         tempSearchStore = [];
        });
       }

     var capitalizedValue =
          value.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);

     if (queryResultSet.length == 0 && value.length == 1) {
       SearchService().searchByName(value).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
         for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
           queryResultSet.add(docs.documents[i].data);
          }
       });
     } else {
        tempSearchStore = [];
        queryResultSet.forEach((element) {
         if (element['item_name'].startsWith(capitalizedValue)) {
           setState(() {
              tempSearchStore.add(element);
           });
         }
        });
     }
   }

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
             appBar: new AppBar(
                title: Text('Firestore search'),
              ),
              body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: TextField(
                   onChanged: (val) {
                   initiateSearch(val);
               },
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                   prefixIcon: IconButton(
                     color: Colors.black,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    iconSize: 20.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                     },
                   ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                    hintText: 'Search by name',
                   border: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))),
              ),
            ),
                 SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                   GridView.count(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
               crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                primary: false,
               shrinkWrap: true,
                children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                   return buildResultCard(element);
               }).toList())
          ]));
       }
   }

      Widget buildResultCard(data) {
        return Card(
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 
    BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
     elevation: 2.0,
      child: Container(
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
         data['item_name'],
         textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
       )))); 
    }
```

> [1]: https://ibb.co/47p2dBD           < image for desired key
>
> [2]: https://ibb.co/kQkWKsq          < image for desired search(in
>   1#document)
>
> [3]: https://ibb.co/MVnBtCd          < image for desired search(in
>   2#document)
>
> [4]  https://ibb.co/yk04RJ4          < image for desired search(in
>   3#document)

Answer (score 0):

I searched in Google’s documentation and I didn’t find anything for Dart and Firestore Collections. But you may try a workaround, [from this third](https://pub.dev/packages/node_interop) party you can find a way to use Node.js with Dart. Furthermore, you can follow the official Google’s [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) to get your data using Node.js.